# Alternative formulation for the gradient of divergence of a vector

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, tensor-calculus

I am trying to derive two identities which are needed in simplifying both solid and fluid momentum balance equations.
Let $A$ be a second-order matrix and $u$ be a vector with three Cartesian components.

*proposition 1:* $$\nabla\cdot(A\nabla\cdot u) = A\cdot\nabla(\nabla \cdot u) +\nabla \cdot u \nabla\cdot A $$

*proof 1:*
In index notation, we have this for LHS:
$$\partial_i (A_{ij} \partial_k u_k)=\partial_i (A_{ij}) \partial_k u_k+A_{ij}\partial_i ( \partial_k u_k)$$
which can be written in engineering notation:
$$\nabla\cdot(A\nabla\cdot u) = (\nabla\cdot A)( \nabla \cdot u) +A\cdot\nabla(\nabla \cdot u) $$
*proposition 2:*
$$ \nabla(\nabla\cdot u)= \nabla\cdot(\nabla u)^T$$
*proof 2:*
There is a proof in wikipedia under "[Divergence of a tensor field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics))" but I don't understand it.

**Questions**
1- Is *proof 1* correct?
2- What is *proof 2*?

Many Thanks.

Comment: If $A$ is a “second-order matrix”, why does $A_i$ have only one index?

Comment: Why does the title talk about “the gradient of divergence of a vector”? The left side is not a gradient of anything.

Comment: Dear G.Smith, I edited the question and changed`A<sub>i</sub>`to `A_ij`. The title talks about the second proposition which is more important to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> 1- Is *proof 1* correct?
> ```

Yes. This is simply the product rule.

> 2- What is proof 2?

The Wikipedia article does not look helpful. Just write it in index notation, and use the fact that partials commute (Clairaut's theorem) (except for functions which are not interesting)
$$ \partial_i \partial_j u_j = \partial_j \partial_i u_j  $$

Personally I would simply give up using "engineering notation" which I regard as having been obsolete since around the end of the C19th. Sometimes I think it is taught only because lecturers think it makes them look clever. Index is clearer and avoids ambiguity.

Comment: The only unsatisfactory consequence of using index notation is that the tensor is then represented by a set of values which are not unique — they depend on the coordinate system. But the tensor notation implies nothing about the coordinate system.

Comment: Not so. The index notation applies in arbitrary  coordinates, and is just as "coordinate free" for that reason. It is clearer, avoids ambiguities, and is more directly applicable when coordinates are chosen, as is inevitably needed for calculation.

Comment: Right, if appearing the metric tensor is not supposed as a complexity!

Comment: yes, but if you are using Cartesian coordinates in Euclidean space (as here) you don't need to worry about that.